# how fIrebase automatically tracking event in mobile application? for example screen_view etc

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

how firebase capture event automatically in mobile application? for example when we open a new screen in mobile app, in firebase screen_view event will get trigger. so i want to know how firebase achieve this. is there any code available for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [automatic screen tracking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) is enabled, Google Analytics for Firebase can use [activity lifecycle events](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc) to detect when a new activity is displayed.  This triggers a screen_view event.